# Access underscore.js from client after using npm in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, underscore.js

In Node.js, I installed the `underscore.js` module. Tried to include it in the layout like this:

```
script(src='/underscore/underscore-min.js')
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

But socket.io is the only one that was found. In `node_modules/socket.io`, there is no socket.io.js file, but in `node_modules/underscore/`, there is a udnerscore-min.js. How exactly am I pulling down socket.io but not underscore.js? Does socket.io run some code and create the socket.io/ directory and put the file there? If so, what method is underscore.js using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your using the express framework with something like:

```
var app = express.createServer(),
          io = io.listen(app);
```

If that is the case then Socket.io will automatically create a route for */socket.io/socket.io.js*. If you want to server *underscore-min.js* you could try symlinking it to a static directory (which is a bit hacky...).

I guess using something like [Stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch) or minifying all your external libraries to one file would be a better solution and it would also reduce the amount of HTTP requests...

**EDIT:**
I just *discovered* [visionmedia/asset](https://github.com/visionmedia/asset) which is really amazing! It still doesn't provide access to your modules inside `node_modules`, but it makes this whole javascript asset management hell not only baerable, but also fun.

You've got an app using express.js? Let's say you want to provider the brwowser with jquery and underscore. All You have to now is:

```
$ asset jquery underscore -c -o public/js

         install : jquery@1.6.2
         install : underscore@1.1.7
        download : jquery@1.6.2
        complete : jquery@1.6.2 public/js/jquery.min.js
        download : underscore@1.1.7
        complete : underscore@1.1.7 public/js/underscore.min.js
```

And that's it! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the cool asset.  I'm using it now.. it is so handy. :)